# How to dynamically create databases and tables using Symfony2 and Doctrine?

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I'm designing a web application that allow user registration. That's pretty simple to persist, since a new user is a **User** entity class that only represents a new line inside a **users** table in a database after created. 
Those users, after logged in, may create a new **Group**, also registered as an entity class. This group would also represent just a new line in another table called **groups**. Everything until here is extremely simple, even for someone like me that only watched a few Lynda video tutorials on Symfony2.

The issue that is preventing me from going further in my development is that the users, weekly, will have to register reports for these groups, that, as the other, will be referencerd as a **Report** class in the `Entity` folder. I know that these registers could simply be added to another table **reports**, with a mapping `OneToMany`, relating the group to the report with a **group_id** column or something like that. But, someday, this table may be, I don't know, a million rows long?

So, I was wondering if there is any way to create a new table **{groupname}_reports** in the database each time a user creates a new group in the web application, in order to make things a bit more organized. Also, how could I send the connection to the correct table using the group name as a parameter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: that wouldn't be a good idea in my opinion.

Comment: If your indexes are correct, a few million records will not be a problem.

Comment: Really? I didn't have that notion, I thought it could be too much. So, I guess the mapping solution would be the best solution, in your opinion?

Comment: if you were to do this an you were using an orm, you would have to decouple reporting from it since an orm would require code generation.

Comment: What you need maybe is a reports table with a column group_id.